# An strange integral: $\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I find this integral on my mathematical analysis exercise book:
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2x}}$$
I tried to rewrite $1+\sin^2x$ as $2-\cos^2x$, expecting trigonometric substitution will be useful and obviously I failed.
One of my classmates said it may be ellipse integral, but as far as I know, elliptic integrals are of the following form:
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}}$$
By the way, the integral calculator on MathDF failed to solve it. So maybe it is true that this integral cannot be expressed in elementary form, then I will tell the author that they mistyped the formula AGAIN.

Comment: [It](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+1%2Fsqrt%281%2Bsin%5E2x%29) is indeed non-elementary

Comment: Hint: let $u=\pi/2-x$ so $\cos x=\sin u$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any relation exists between this integral and elliptic integral s?

Comment: Set $k=\mathrm i$ in the elliptic integral to obtain your desired integral. It is still well defined.

Comment: [for example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=EllipticF%5Bx%2C-1%5D)